How to pass custom attributes in cartCreate mutation in shopify graphql?
I want to pass other properties of product like Height/width and uploaded image url but there is no proper documentation for it
this is mutation
mutation {
  cartCreate(
    input: {
      lines: [
        {
          attributes: [
            {
              key: "id", 
              value: "gid://shopify/Product/9895276099"
            }, 
            {
              key: "title", 
              value: "Heart  Handle Photo Mug"
            }, 
            {
              key: "size", 
              value: "Heart  Handle Photo Mug"
            },
            {
              key: "Upload Image", 
              value: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0617/4851/0900/uploads/2ecba24ecb37c3c1223d3d0f91a77d67.jpeg"
            }
          ], 
          quantity: 1, 
          merchandiseId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/36607622083"}]}
  ) {
    cart {
      id
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      lines(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            quantity
            merchandise {
              ... on ProductVariant {
                id
                title
                price {
                  amount
                  currencyCode
                }
                
                image {
                  id
                  originalSrc
                }
              }
            }
            attributes {
              key
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
      attributes {
        key
        value
      }
      estimatedCost {
        totalAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        subtotalAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        totalTaxAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
        totalDutyAmount {
          amount
          currencyCode
        }
      }
      buyerIdentity {
        email
        phone
        customer {
          id
        }
        countryCode
      }
      discountCodes {
        code
      }
    }
    userErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}

I want to pass extra attributes like to get height/width/image url and placing order so i can get details of extra parameters in order list
{
              key: "Upload Image", 
              value: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0a24ecb37c3c1223d3d0f91a77d67.jpeg"
}

but this uploaded image is not showing after place order in shopify
